# Grub stopped booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, windows-8

everytime I restart my computer or shut it down it boots straight back into windows 8

It used to boot into GRUB but for some reason it stopped.How do I fix this?

Comment: May be best to see details, post link to summary report in above: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are booting up your computer, hold the  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  key to boot into Grub
and if that doesn´t work, try holding  <kbd>ESC</kbd>  or  <kbd>Enter.</kbd>  You should only have to hold them for about 3-5 seconds, if that doesn't work, make sure Grub is installed.